# Nested functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-analysis

I am learning Python and I currently have a function that is long and somewhat repetitive. Please see below: **Goal:** To reduce the function into parts so I can understand how this process works better.

```
def play_game(questions,answers):
    '''Begins checking user input to answers /
       fills in the blanks with correct answer /
       prompts user with same question if answer is Wrong
       :param questions: feeds .split() list to find __1__
       :param answers: searches for answer and replaces blank __1__
       :return: replaces correct answer in questions param.
       '''
    print questions
    user_input = raw_input("Fill in the blank: ")
    if user_input == answers[0]:
        questions = questions.replace('__1__', answers[0])
    if user_input != answers[0]:
        user_input = raw_input("Wrong answer, you have 4 guesses left. ")
    print questions
    user_input = raw_input("\n Please answer second question: ")
    if user_input == answers[1]:
        questions += questions.replace('__2__', answers[1])
    if user_input != answers[1]:
        user_input = raw_input("\n Incorrect, you have 3 guesses left. ")
    print questions
```

This process will continue for 5 guesses. I want to stress the importance of the same question being asked again if user guesses incorrectly, they will also have a guess reduced from 5 to 4, etc. Should I be using a loop to automate here?

```
print questions
#for answer in answers:
# process answer
user_input = raw_input("Fill in the blank: ")
if user_input == answers[0]:
```

Comment: yes, use a loop. What does this have to do with nested functions?

Comment: Also, you should be using `else`. Instead of `if a==b: do_this()` `if a!=b:do_that()` you should do `if a==b: do_this()` `else: do_that()`

Comment: @PM 2Ring Will that still check if the answer is not in the list?

Comment: Also sorry for the repetitiveness, any understanding is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SheperdsonBrown if you want it to perform the check you can do  `if a==b: do_this()` then `elif a!=b:do_that()` But `a!=b & a==b` shouldn't be `True` in many occasion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
for guess in range(4):
    print "Guess", guess + 1

# Put your game function here

    if guess == 3:
        print "Game Over!"
```

Comment: like so ? for guess in range(4):
    print "Guess", guess + 1
def play_game(questions,answers):

Comment: @SheperdsonBrown - Yes, something like that